# django-admin runserver error

Tags: python-2.7, django-admin, django-1.9

I set virtualenv for python 2.7

```
16% source Work/Django/env/bin/activate
```

next create project

```
django-admin startproject myproject
```

create app

```
cd myproject
django-admin startapp contact
```

and try run dev server

```
16% django-admin runserver
```

I receive an error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/bin/django-admin", line 11, in 
>       sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 345, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 195, in fetch_command
>       klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/**init**.py", line 39, in load_command_class
>       module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/**init**.py", line 37, in import_module
>       **import**(name)
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 16, in 
>       from django.db.migrations.executor import MigrationExecutor
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 7, in 
>       from .loader import MigrationLoader
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 10, in 
>       from django.db.migrations.recorder import MigrationRecorder
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 12, in 
>       class MigrationRecorder(object):
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 26, in MigrationRecorder
>       class Migration(models.Model):
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 27, in Migration
>       app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py", line 1072, in **init**
>       super(CharField, self).**init**(*args, **kwargs)
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/**init**.py", line 166, in **init**
>       self.db_tablespace = db_tablespace or settings.DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 55, in **getattr**
>       self._setup(name)
>     File "/home/dima/Work/Django/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/**init**.py", line 41, in _setup
>       % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
>   django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
>   How fix this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at what the `manage.py` script does (this script was created inside the `myproject` directory when you ran `django-admin startproject myproject`), it exports the environment variable `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` and then runs `django-admin` (well, it does it through `django.core` but it does pretty much that).

`django-admin` needs to know the **python module** of the settings for your project, and that information is present in that environment variable.

---

Therefore, inside the `myproject` directory, you shall either run:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and the `manage.py` script will do the environment setup for you, **or** you can force `django-admin` to read the settings location from the command line:

```
django-admin runserver --pythonpath=. --settings="myproject.settings"
```

The `--pythonpath` switch is not needed if you included your project directory on the default pyhton path.

Comment: it will work without the ".settings" when giving the project name string for --settings

Answer (score 0):

```
mkdir djangoproject

cd djangoproject/

pip install virtualenv

virtualenv myvenv

pip freeze

which python

source myvenv/bin/activate

pip install django

pip freeze

django-admin startproject myproject

cd myproject/

python manage.py runserver
```

Your project will be start successfully

```
django-admin startapp myapp
```

Now, you need to make some settings related to the application you created. (settings.py & urls.py)